# How to fetch value from auth.config.ts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular7

What I am looking for is to, extract value from scope which i get after auth.
Is there any way in angular to get this value?

auth.config.ts

```
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';

export const authConfig: AuthConfig = {
  // you would get this values from `environment.ts` in real use.
  loginUrl: ********************,
  clientId: ***************,
  redirectUri: ********,
  scope: 'mail username company',
// some more
};
```

I want to get the value of scope: "mail" and all?

Comment: What do you mean by `Is there any way in angular to get this value.` Can you please make it clear

Comment: @TonyNgo i want to get the value of mail or username etc.

Comment: In where ? Which file ? Can you tell more

Comment: @TonyNgo i have mentioned above the code.  As per discussion, let's say I need to get value in any of my components?